# How to iterate over time interval in a two-level dict in Python?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, timestamp

I'm creating a program that will read a set of XML files in a directory and prints a summary report of the content, like so:

```
  timestamp    TICK12   TICK13   TICK14
------------   ------   ------   ------
06-26 09:00         1        0        0
06-26 09:01         0       33        0
06-26 09:02         0        0       32
06-26 09:03         0       19        0
06-26 09:04         0       12        0
```

Each column has the timestamp **(by the minute)** followed by one column per print zone found, and each line shows the timestamp and the number of requests for each print zone during that time period. Each minute should be accounted for, even if 0 requests were made, and the program should accept zone names from the CL so that only those zones are reported.

Now, I'm having difficulty traversing the timestamps inside my dict() such that the output includes not only the timestamps pulled from my `dir` of XML files, but also the timestamps in between **(minute-by-minute)**. The timestamps in the XML files are formatted like so:

**2017-06-22T06:34:21**

Any advice on design is also welcome, I'm new to Python!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob
import time

global FPATH1
FPATH1 = r'/Users/xd/Documents/pz/testdir'
os.chdir(FPATH1)

timeheader = 'timestamp'
myarg = sysargv[1]

def main():
    print('%11s %20s' % (timeheader, myarg))
    print('-----------\t\t-------')
    parseandformat()

format_old = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
format_new = '%%m-%d %H:%M'
def parseandformat():
    for fn in glob.glob(os.path.join(FPATH1, '*.xml')):
        DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fn)
        collection = DOMTree.documentElement
        ts = collection.getElementByTagName('TimeStamp')[0].firstChild.data
        pz = collection.getElementByTagName('PrintZone')[0].firstChild.data
        ts = datetime.strptime(timestamp, format_old).strftime(format_new) # ??
        d[ts] = d.get(ts, {})
        d[ts][pz] = 1 + d[ts].get(pz, 0)

    keys = d.keys()
    mintime = min(keys)
    maxtime = max(keys)

    for k in keys:
        print '%11 %20s' % (k, d[k].get(myarg, 0))

    for result in perdelta(mintime, maxtime, timedelta(seconds=60)):
        print result

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

main()
```

Comment: may be easier to convert you dictionary or xml files into a pandas dataframe, since your desired output is already in the form of a dataframe

Comment: Okay, much appreciated but I want to understand a possible solution first before I implement an easy fix.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Records from `d` before `keys = d.keys()`.